# why python not recognizing my project packages in import statements

Tags: python, import, project, package

I'm trying to import my packages from the same project I am using. But I'm getting ImportError: No module named main_package.sub_package

I'm using python2.7
My project structure is

```
my_project/main_package/sub_package/file_a
my_project/main_package/sub_package/file_b
```

and the following row:

`from main_package.sub_package import file_b`

isn't working when we add it in file_a. and isn't working from other packages in main_package.

This does work on other computers. 
I tried to add all of their elements to my sys.path. 
I also have anaconda installed in my computer, and I tried to use  the following interpreters: `~/anaconda/bin/python2.7`,  `~/anaconda/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` in all directories.?

Comment: Yes, please show us your `__init__.py`.

Comment: Please also use the *actual* names of your modules (instead of `sub_package` etc.). If one of your packages is called the same as a standard library module, name shadowing issues might be part of the problem.

Comment: I have __init__.py in all directories, and packages. It works on the original computer it was written on. I pulled it from git, and it doesn't work on my computer. 
The __init__.py files are empty. 

As for the original names, some of them are confidential, but are named after my customers, and don't have a standard library module name. It's:
customer_name/customer_name-python/ptml/doc2vec/constants.py
customer_name/customer_name-python/ptml/doc2vec/doc2vec.py

And in doc2vec.py I have a row:
from ptml.doc2vec import constants

And I'm getting: "ImportError: No module named ptml.doc2vec"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project there should be src directory. In your case my_project/**src**/main_package/.

Inside IDE (I use PyCharm) right click on it and select "Mark Directory As" -> "Sources Root".